# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para descargarme archivos de una fecha específica con OpenSSH?

Tags: web

mi problema es el siguiente:
Tengo un sitio web, y hubo un problema y se borraron archivos. No tengo yo almacenado en mi PC los archivos esos (ya que fueron agregados hace unos meses, y no hice en su momento un nuevo backup de la carpeta que los contenía). Consulté al servicio técnico del hosting que tengo contratado, y para poder acceder al contenido de los backups realizados en el servidor, me dijeron que puede ser sólo mediante ssh (ya que el panel de configuración del hosting tiene la posibilidad de recuperar backups, pero no de ver su contenido antes de hacerlo, y necesito ver el contenido antes para no cometer un error), es decir, sólo puedo hacerlo descargándome los archivos del servidor a mi PC mediante ssh. Sin embargo ellos no me ofrecen ayuda con ssh por ser un servicio externo a ellos.

Lo que necesito es saber si es posible descargarme archivos de una fecha específica, y en ese caso, cómo hacerlo.
Y si no, si alguien me podría facilitar documentación (si es posible, en Español, y si no, en Inglés) lo agradecería, ya que tampoco estoy logrando encontrar documentación completa que me ayude a entender cómo, por ejemplo, descargarme un directorio completo.

El servidor es Linux, y mi computadora tiene Windows 7 (sin posibilidad de actualizar el SO actualmente). El servidor contratado es Donweb, y el panel de control que utilizan es Ferozo.

Comment: Aunque el acceso ssh es común a diversos operativos no estaría de más que añadas información concreta del servidor (SO, versión, panel de control...) quizá algún usuario tenga experiencia con un sistema igual y facilite el proceso de restauración.

Comment: @Fly gracias por la ayuda, ahí edité la publicación y añadí la información al final.

Comment: Supongo que tendrás cierta urgencia, los próximos backups podrían machacar los actuales. ¿has intentado algo ya? Te recomiendo que descargues putty (consola) y winscp (escritorio), que son clientes ssh con los que conectarte al Debian ¿has usado alguno de ellos? ¿como estas de familiarizado con linux? ¿sabes la ruta de los backups actuales?

Comment: Debes darle un `man find` y te saldra time mtime y otras opciones disponibles para buscar por fecha

Comment: @Fly me descargué winscp, pero no conozco los comandos necesarios para fijarme por fecha. La urgencia la tengo sí, en realidad el que más la tiene es mi jefe, así que estoy complicado con esto, no encuentro ayuda por ningún lado. Ya me descargué OpenSSH, Winscp, probé los comandos que encontré pero ninguno está relacionado a fechas, sólo a "subir y descargar archivos", ni siquiera encontré la manera de descargar un directorio completo. Conozco la ruta de los backups, esa información sí me facilitaron los del servicio técnico.

Comment: @Bryro gracias, voy a probar eso y vuelvo a aquí.

Comment: @AgustínVis no tienes la posibilidad de descargar los backups y una vez en tu equipo descomprimir y revisar con tus herramientas habituales?

Comment: Hola @Fly, no, no tengo esa posibilidad, no tengo acceso a la carpeta de backups excepto por ssh. Tengo que probar lo que me dijo Bryro y vuelvo a dar el feedback.